# preg_replace Remove comment text in content

Tags: the-content

In post content, i insert a text like below

```
 abc acb acb acb
<!--REMOVE--> text to remove <!--ENDREMOVE-->
 abc acb acb acb
 abc acb acb acb
<!--REMOVE--> text to remove <!--ENDREMOVE-->
 abc acb acb acb
 abc acb acb acb
<!--REMOVE--> text to remove <!--ENDREMOVE-->
 abc acb acb acb
```

I want to get only

```
abc acb acb acb
abc acb acb acb
abc acb acb acb
abc acb acb acb
abc acb acb acb
abc acb acb acb
```

And i run this code

```
 function remove($content){
    preg_match_all("/<!--REMOVE-->.*<!--ENDREMOVE-->/", $content, $matches);
    var_dump($matches);
    $content= preg_replace("/<!--REMOVE-->.*<!--ENDREMOVE-->/", '', $content);

    return $content;
 }
 add_filter('the_content', 'remove', 1);
```

but it does not work. What is the problem ?

The real result from above code is

```
abc acb acb acb
abc acb acb acb
```

And var_dump is one result, not 3 results

```
array
    0 => <!--REMOVE--> text to remove <!--ENDREMOVE-->
         abc acb acb acb
         abc acb acb acb
         <!--REMOVE--> text to remove <!--ENDREMOVE-->
         abc acb acb acb
         abc acb acb acb
         <!--REMOVE--> text to remove <!--ENDREMOVE-->
```

The right way is

```
array
   0 => <!--REMOVE--> text to remove <!--ENDREMOVE-->

   1 => <!--REMOVE--> text to remove <!--ENDREMOVE-->

   2 => <!--REMOVE--> text to remove <!--ENDREMOVE-->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are having with your code is this line:

```
$conten = preg_replace("/<!--REMOVE-->.*<!--ENDREMOVE-->/", '', $content);
```

`$conten` is assigned, but `$content` is returned.

```
function remove( $content ) {
    return preg_replace( '/<!--REMOVE-->.*<!--ENDREMOVE-->/', '', $content );
}
```

---

After question edit:

> The real result from above code is
>
> ```
> abc acb acb acb
> abc acb acb acb
> ```

`.*` is greedy. It finds all matches up to the last `<!--ENDREMOVE-->`.

`.*?` is not greedy. It finds all matches up to the first `<!--ENDREMOVE-->`.

Use this function:

```
function remove( $content ) {
    return preg_replace( '/<!--REMOVE-->.*?<!--ENDREMOVE-->/', '', $content );
}
```

Comment: i have updated my questions, please check